# Proper structure for flexible fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a app where I have only one Login activity and one main activity. I replace fragments down to three level ie like A->B->C or A->B->D and more scenarios like this.I keep them on back stack and on back press retrieve them.Like on backpress of C , B appears. I am having a scenario where I receive push notification then on click of it the app should redirect to C. Now to achieve it I have to go through the launch screen. It means that before clicking on notification if I am on D and I get notification for C then I will land on C , but on backpress I will not come to D but to B because A->B>C . So is there a structure for one activity and all fragments where even if I click on notification,I can get back the flow as it is before the notification arrived ..??? ie directly maintain C to D and then regular flow as it is.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend slightly on what the contents of those fragments are but I think actually the Android docs would suggest the behaviour you have at the moment is actually the correct one. Essentially once you've navigated into the app from a notification you the navigation should be the same as if you'd entered that point in the app normally by navigating through the screens. It should have the previous navigation history cleared.

The docs elaborate on this:
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#into-your-app

Comment: But in case I need to achieve it, is there a way I may do it, without creating much of issues in normal flow.?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener to your fragment hosted activity,override methods then on onTabSelected get tab position(Let's say tabPosition),from this position try following code in same activity(with required changes):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        if(tabPosition!=0)
        {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tabPosition- 1);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: I am not using tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom backstack of you own.

So if you have a history that looks like this:

A->B->C->D

If an event then causes the history to add C once more, e.g. the notification you specify above, then what you specify above suggests you want the history to look like this afterward:

A->B->C->D->C

And what you get currently, which you don't want, is this:

A->B->C

To do this you can implement custom fragment history handling in your Activity. Where you would normally add your fragment transition to the backstack, instead add the fragment to an ArrayList or similar entity. I have thrown together some code below:

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentHistory = new ArrayList<>();

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToHistory) {

       // your fragment transition code here without adding to backstack

       // add the fragment to your custom history
       if (addToHistory) {
           mFragmentHistory.add(fragment);
       }

 }
```

You will then need to implement handling code in the onBackPressed method of the same Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     // if the history is not at the "top", i.e. only one (or 0) fragments in history
     if (mFragmentHistory.size() > 1) {
       // remove the last (==current) fragment from history
       mFragmentHistory.remove(mFragmentHistory.size() - 1);

       // get new last fragment from history - this is now the one to load 
       Fragment loadFragment = mFragmentHistory.get(mFragmentHistory.size() - 1);

       // load this fragment, don't add it to the history
       loadFragment(loadFragment, false);

     } else {
        // perform default system back or implement your custom handler here
        super.onBackPressed();
     }
}
```

You will have to consider maintaining state over Activity restarts (screen rotation etc.).

Comment: Also I forgot to mention this, every fragment is loading on click of a grid view. Anyways In case do maintain array list I will need to maintain there state ,which is done by default when I add them to backstack . But if I keep on loading them there state would be lost right..???

Comment: The fragment still exists if it is added to an ArrayList as there is a reference to the object, it's not like an Activity. The default backstack is basically just a collection wrapped in handling code.